# XAMPP's Config.php overriding my own config.php

Tags: php, xampp

It has been bugging me forever and I only just figured out why it was happening.
I have the following structure:

`index.php`: `require('php/session.php');`
`php/session.php`: `require('config.php');`
`php/config.php`: `echo 'hi';`

Now, if I open `index.php`, nothing is printed. Actually, `config.php` is supposed to define a bunch of variables, and I'm getting errors since these variables are never defined.

Now, it turns out that the `require('config.php');` actually refers to `XAMPP/php/pear/Config.php` instead of the file in the local directory. How is that possible, and is there any way to avoid it without having to rename my script (I mean come on, `config.php` has got to be the most common name ever).

I should note that its a development machine and its running Windows, so case difference doesn't save me.

Comment: Can't reproduce your error. (With the php directory you don't mean: `xampp/php/` right?)

Comment: What is your [include path](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)?

Comment: Its a basic XAMPP installation, I have it set up this way on several PCs and all have this same issue. php directory is just a folder in my webroot, not anywhere near the xampp directory. And yeah, include path is `include_path=".;C:\Program Files (x86)\XAMPP\php\PEAR"`, would changing it break anything?